# How to create list in HTML dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In my jQuery mobile app, I want to display the result from a web service in a list. How do I create the list dynamically?

Comment: can u suggest some other examples?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048360/dynamically-creating-jquery-mobile-pages-using-jquery-templates and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039428/jquery-mobile-dynamically-creating-form-elements

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var arr = ["list", "items", "here"];
$("div").append("<ul></ul>");
for(var i in arr) {
    var li = "<li>";
    $("ul").append(li.concat(arr[i]))
}
```

Comment: In that list, how can I get the selected value?

Comment: In this list, there is no "selected" value.  It is a display only list.  Build it with **select** and **option** instead of **ul** and **li** if you want a selection list.

Answer (score 17):

Better yet,

```
$.each(
    a ,
    function(i,v) {
        $("#target_id").append("<li>" + v + "</li>") ;
    }
) ;
```

Where `a` is an Array of Objects for the list content, `i` is the index variable passed to the callback function by `jQuery.each` (`$.each`) and `v`is the value for that index.

---

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ .

Comment: I wouldn't call that "better"; the accepted answer is pure JS, without any dependencies like jQuery (which is needed less and less as JavaScript continues to mature).

Comment: @JeffDickey First of all, the accepted answer also uses jQuery (note the `$("div").append(...)`). I also hope you realize that this post is from 2011 and that OP explicitely states that he's using jQuery. Just sayin' :D